# is there an example in planar graph that using probabilistic methods

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The probabilistic method is a technique for proving the
existence of an object with certain properties by showing that
a random object chosen from an appropriate probability
distribution has the desired properties with positive probability.
For example: [image]
https://cpb-us-east-1-juc1ugur1qwqqqo4.stackpathdns.com/sites.psu.edu/dist/f/7257/files/2013/10/The-Probabilistic-Method.pdf

> If $\binom nk \cdot 2^{1-\binom k2}<1$, then $R(k,k)>n$. Thus $R(k,k)>\lfloor 2^{k/2}\rfloor$ for each $k\ge3$.

Is there any example for  getting some properties on planar graphs using the probabilistic method?
We know that discharging can get many useful local structures.
I feel that the probability method is also a way of counting skill.

Comment: the crossing number inequality has a short probabilistic proof, for example

Comment: @FedorPetrov: nice answer, but it's not quite a result about planar graphs. One problem with the question is that there's not an obvious simple random model of planar graphs...

Comment: @Sam Hopkins Thanks!  For probability method, I am a beginner.  My quetion is: For some specific graph classes(for example: minimum degree is greater than 5 , whether we can get some properties.  just example may be Inappropriate.

Theorem: If a planar graph has minimum degree 5, then it either has an edge with endpoints both of degree 5 or one with endpoints of degrees 5 and 6.

Comment: The structural results you're talking about appear to have a pretty different flavor than the things proved with the probabilistic method (which are usually inequalities...) but who knows